# Number of solutions of $a^3=e$ in $C_9$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Number of solutions of $a^3=e$ in $C_9$

The solution goes: $a^3=e$ if and only if $a$ lies in the unique subgroup of $C_9$ of order $3$ thus there are $3$ solutions.

I'm questioning why?

Answer (score 0):

Note that $a^3=e\implies o(a)=3\implies $ the cyclic group generated by $a$ i.e $\langle a \rangle =3$  and in a cyclic group of order $9$ there exists exactly one subgroup for each divisor $d$ of $9$ and hence unique.

Hence the elements are $\{e,a,a^2\}$ which satisfy $a^3=e$

Comment: But $a$ might be the identity? Can you elaborate about uniqueness ?

Comment: See the edits@ZHU

Comment: Any more doubts ?You can consider accepting it then

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you are asking how many elements of order $3$ there are in $C_9$. You can view this a few ways. Note that every cyclic group is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_9$ so the question boils down to asking how many elements of order $3$ there are in $\mathbb{Z}_9$? Since there are a few elements, we can analyze this and get
$$3, 6$$
Note that this is precisely $\phi(3) = 2$. This is not a coincidence. We can do better though, we can generalize this in $\mathbb{Z}_n \approx C_n$ by noting that $a$ generates $\mathbb{Z}_9$. If $a^k$ has order $k$, then since there is only one subgroup of order $k$ in $\mathbb{Z}_n$ where $k$ divides $n$ and since $|a^j| = k$ if $k$ and $j$ are coprime....this is precisely $\phi(k)$!

Since you need to consider other elements whose order is a divisor of $3$, note that $3$ is a prime, so only $1$ is a unique distinct factor of it, so only $e$ has this property.